# Logging JdbcTemplate query execution time

Tags: java, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I'm writing an app that is working with db via `org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate`. I need to log execution of those queries. So I have methods that have some jdbctemplate logic, for example

```
List<Map<String, Object>> data = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(queryTables);
```

I need to log time of execution of this query but not of the all method.
I can do that via milliseconds subtraction. But it is not the case if I have 1500 methods or even more. So is there any annotation or any other method that can help me to log execution time?

Comment: Where does JdbcTemplate have its origin? Using Aspects might be an option but this creates overhead which must at least be kept in mind.

Comment: In short no. You can use what @Markus suggests or look into the DB itself. It may allow you to that programmatically

Comment: Im not sure whats the best way to calculate the time but I made an example code where Im calculating the execution time of multiples methods. Hope it works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27112162/why-is-multiplied-many-times-faster-than-taking-the-square-root

Comment: Oh and some databases allow query logging. This would have the advantage to factor out network and stuff from the measurement.

Comment: my application needs to work with any db so that is not the solution

Answer (score 2):

1. spring use [StopWatch](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/StopWatch.html) for mesure execution time , also apache has the same [StopWatch](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/StopWatch.html) . example for stopwatch - https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/08/measure-execution-time-in-java-spring.html
2. use aop for execution time . here are example https://veerasundar.com/blog/2010/01/spring-aop-example-profiling-method-execution-time-tutorial/

   with aop and custom annotation you can mark method that you want to log execution time.

aop - it's not so big overhead , when you use @Transactional you also use aop , so you already have this overhad

---

if you want to log execution time only for dbcTemplate.queryForList() and in couple plase , use stopwatch. or you can create your own util method (wrap dbcTemplate.queryForList()) , something like :

```
public static List<?> queryForListWithLogExecution(String sql){
     List<?> result;
     //measuring elapsed time using Spring StopWatch
        StopWatch watch = new StopWatch();
        watch.start();
        list = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(queryTables); 
        watch.stop();
        logger.info("Total execution time in millis: {0}", watch.getTotalTimeMillis());
        return result;
}
```